# Empty results in dynamical form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, web

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from .forms import TestForm
from django import forms
def TestView(request,id):
    test = Tests.objects.get(id=id)
    queshions = Queshions.objects.filter(test=test)
    form = TestForm(queshions=queshions)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = TestForm(data=request.POST, queshions=queshions)
        print(form)
        print(form.is_valid())
    else:
        context = {'queshions':queshions,'test': test,'form':form }
        return render(request,'testview.html',context)
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms


class TestForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queshions = kwargs.pop('queshions')
    super(TestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for queshion in queshions:
        self.fields[queshion.id] = forms.CharField(label=queshion.text)
```

POST request is correct, but form.is_valid returns False, and when i am printing form it writes
"This field is required." like it is empty

Comment: Show your models with more explanation.

Comment: Can you add the content of the request and the exact field that it says it's empty?

Comment: POST request looks like this:
 <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Q45CRoN8D4IFCsJtZcciqkUB3oZfCnNrfQRgm3POMy2W9bdMDF3iLUzwfhBj8sW4'], '1': ['Answer1'], '2': ['Answer2'], '3': ['Answer3'], '4': ['Answer4'], 'submit': ['Submit']}>

but when i am printing form in console after processing it this is what happens:
<td>
      <ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
      <input type="text" name="1" required id="id_1">


    </td>

Comment: Also, all fields are becoming empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names should be strings:

```py
# self.fields[queshion.id] = forms.CharField(label=queshion.text)     # Change this
self.fields[str(queshion.id)] = forms.CharField(label=queshion.text)  # to this
```

The keys in `request.POST` are strings:

```py
form = TestForm(data=request.POST, queshions=queshions)
```